# Difference equation system solution

Tags: recurrence-relations

A system is written

$$
S_n = f^nS_0 \\
P_n = p(f-1)f^{n-1}S_0
$$

for $n\leq T$. For $n\geq T$:

$$
S_{n+1} = f(S_n-P_n ) \\
P_{n+1} = p(f-1)(S_n-P_n )
$$

The constants $S_0,f,p$ are all positive real (and $p<1$). I would like to obtain a general equation for $S_n$ and $P_n$ at time $n\geq T$. (No need to worry about $n\leq T$ since the equations are already in terms of the constants alone.) Is this possible?

Summation, product etc operators are fine

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What can you say about $\frac{S_n}{P_n}$?

Comment: Thanks! That actually helped a lot